# Incorrect datetime value en MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

Estaba intentando registrar mediante una query en c# el `datetime.now` en una base de datos MySQL

Lo que hago en c# es:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cola_llamadas(fecha,queueName,cola)" +
                  "VALUES(DATE_FORMAT('"+DateTime.Now+"', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'),'XXXX'," + Convert.ToInt32(subaux) +")";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

El string del query está bien al parecer:

```
"INSERT INTO cola_llamadas(fecha,queueName,cola) VALUES(DATE_FORMAT('24/10/2017 16:35:03', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'),'XXXX',2)"
```

El problema está en que quiero meterlo en una base de datos con formato de

`dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS`<--- espero explicarme con esto. ¿Como puedo convertir el string? En SQL lo haría de forma sencilla con To_Date, ¿pero en MySQL?

Este es el error que me devuelve exactamente:

```
#1292 - incorrect datetime value: '24/10/2017' 16:35:03'
```

Debe de ser algo super sencillo, pero ahora mismo no caigo y es la primera vez que uso MySQL como tal.

Comment: Oye me parece que tu ejemplo esta un poco incorrecto como si no tuviera ejemplos, codigos, y patrones que indiquen que la asersion de ejemplo y a cuestinoamientoi de prueba/error o desbordamieno de pila por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El insert debería de estar así

```
"INSERT INTO cola_llamadas(fecha,queueName,cola) VALUES('24/10/2017 16:35:03','XXXX',2)"
```

y funcionaría perfecto.
Ahora bien en C# puede hacer lo siguiente.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings
Ademas te aconsejaría utiliar EntityFramework ya que facilita mucho el manejo de datos y consultas a la db https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb399182(v=vs.100).aspx

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO cola_llamadas(fecha,queueName,cola)" +
                  "VALUES("+DateTime.Now.ToString("format")+"','XXXX'," + Convert.ToInt32(subaux) +")";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó.